# Al guardar un dato en una tabla anidada basandose en otra tabla esta pierde datos

Tags: php, mysql

Poseo una tabla anidada donde se almacenan proyectos y alumnos llamada Proyecto_alumno, esta tiene como funcion registrar alumnos a los proyectos, los alumnos y los proyectos se guardan por separado.

Ocurre que al inscribir alumnos a un proyecto, el proyecto sin saber porque en su campo de titulo se borra, queda vacio, estando antes el proyecto guardado con todos sus campos en la base de datos.

Les dejo el codigo con el cual guardo los alumnos en la tabla anidada con el ID del proyecto seleccionado.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id)
{
$alumno = array('proy_id' => NULL, 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'alum_id' => $alumno_id);
bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno);
}
header("Location: listado4.php");
exit;
```

Seguido el código que agrega los alumnos 
"bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar"

```
function bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($d)
{
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO 
                    proyecto_alumno (proy_alum_id, proy_id, alum_id) 
                VALUES 
                    ('%s','%s','%s')",
    $d['proy_alum_id'],
    $d['proy_id'],
    $d['alum_id']
);
$res = sql($sql);
$id  = sql2value("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
return $id;
}
```

Tabla de Proyecto

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto` (
  `proy_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `proy_deno` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `plan_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `objg_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `obje_proy` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fech_insc` date NOT NULL,
  `nomb_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `resp_comu` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parr_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `deta` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `esta_proy_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `telf_inst` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telf_resp` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `obsv_proy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `proy_carr_id` int(2) NOT NULL
```

Tabla Proyecto_alumno

```
CREATE TABLE `proyecto_alumno` (
  `proy_alum_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `proy_id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `alum_id` int(9) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

FORMULARIO COMPLETO DE REGISTRO DE ALUMNOS

http://www.miblocdenotas.com/104107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu fallo esta en el `FOR EACH'

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id)
{
$alumno = array(**'proy_id' => NULL**, 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'alum_id' => $alumno_id);
bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno);
}
```

Estas igualando al principio `proy_id` a `NULL`. Prueba cambiando ese código por:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id)
    {
    $alumno = array('proy_requ_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_alum_id'], 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'alum_id' => $alumno_id);
    bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno);
    }
```

Comment: Mira a ver el campo $_REQUEST, que he puesto, he intuido que era ese nombre, pero al no tener el html, me lo he inventado un poco

Comment: Fijate en la parte de `$alumno = array('proy_alum_id' => NULL` , esto hace que el campo sea el NULL

Comment: @Victor Alejandro Alvarado Vilo si te funciona selecciona la pregunta como `Aceptada` para otra gente que puede tener algun problema similar sepa la solución

Comment: Edita el código y po en el `HTML`y la definición de las tablas a ver si puedo ayudarte

Comment: El Formulario donde recoges los datos

Comment: ya lo solucione, creo, habia un error en el archivo 

iba esto:

<form id="frmIns" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="proc_inscripcion4.php" role="form">

y tenia era

<form id="frmIns" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="proc_modif.php" role="form">